# getting the value out of a select tag (automatic made)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a starter in php and I want to get the value out of the select tag. 
I am using PHP en MYSQLi, and use mysqli_fetch_row to create the tag.

I open my mysqli server, get all the values I need and it all works fine. I just want to get the selected value of the user, in the select menu.
My code is:

```
 <?php
  if(isset($_POST['verzenden']))
  { ... = $_POST['$data[0]'] ;}
?>

<form method="post">
    <?php

                $cmd = "SELECT * FROM gegevens";
                $result = mysqli_query($verbinding, $cmd);

                     echo '<select>';
                # zet rij per rij de resultaten in de tabel
                while($data = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
                  {

                    echo ("<option value='$data[0]'>$data[0]</option><br>");

                  }; 
                    echo '</select>';


                       mysqli_close($verbinding);
      ?>


<button name="verzenden"> Verzend uw keuze </button>
```

Comment: your `<select>` has no name attribute

Comment: If you want to get the selected value you need to use AJAX: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/  So you need a dynamic page.

Comment: Is it possible just with php, i'm not into AJAX..

Comment: @RobinV it is possible. Please see the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to get the value when the form is posted, you must add a `NAME` attibute to your `SELECT` tag. For example:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['verzenden']))
    { ... = $_POST['verzenden']; }
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];">
<?php
    $cmd = "SELECT * FROM gegevens";
    $result = mysqli_query($verbinding, $cmd);
    echo "<select name='verzenden'>\r\n";
    # zet rij per rij de resultaten in de tabel
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
        echo ("\t<option value='{$data[0]}'>{$data[0]}</option>\r\n");
    }; 
    echo "</select>\r\n";
    mysqli_close($verbinding);
?>
<button name="verzenden"> Verzend uw keuze </button>
```

The `NAME` is important. You can then get the value from `$_POST['verzenden']` in your PHP after the form is posted.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering.. I still don't get it, what do you mean with the \r \n? Dreamweaver keeps giving me a yellow background by your post..